# It only return one letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

It only returns one letter. But i want to return all letters in one line, if i reurn in loop, it returns 1st letter. If returned outside loop it returns last letter.

```
def cip(pas):
    for i in pas:
        asci = ord(i)
        encryption = asci + 4
        reverse = chr(encryption)
        return reverse

a = 'lipps'
b = 'hello'
if cip(b) == a:
    print('hey')
```

Comment: You replace `reverse` for every iteration of the loop. You need to initialize it to an empty string and then concatenate your "encrypted" character to the total string.

Comment: `return` exits the function, you might want to make a list or string to append to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning early in the loop, you need to build up a string and return that. Either just return a joint string or build it up

```
 "".join(chr(ord(s)+4) for s in pas)
```

```
def cip(pas):
    ret_val = ""
    for i in pas:
        asci = ord(i)
        encryption = asci + 4
        ret_val += chr(encryption)
    return ret_val
```